# open thunderbird at startup in the tray

Tags: shell, scripting

I am new to linux and I recently started to use arch linux (with KDE).

I am trying to set up a simple script that, at the startup, should en thunderbird and put it in the tray.

To this end, I added in the folder

`/home/dario/.config/autostart-scripts`

a file named

`thunderbird-script`

containing the following commands

`sleep 10 kdocker thunderbird &`

(of course, I have kdocker installed)

However, the script does not do the job.

Somebody can explain me why it does not work and how I should proceed?

Comment: [birdtray](https://github.com/gyunaev/birdtray)

Comment: @KamilCuk thank you! For educational purposes, do you know why my approach does not work?